# In centos mouse and keyboard does not work after deleting /var/cache

Tags: centos, centos6, centos6.5

After deleting accidentely `/var/cache` in centos 6.5, restart my PC, the mouse and keyboard does not work anymore

Answer (score 2):

I've found some people with a similar issue and their solution may work for you. What they did was run the HAL daemon as root:
    `hald --verbose=yes --daemon=no`. They received an error that a file could not be created in `/var/cache/hald/`. The problem was resolved by creating this directory and re-running the daemon. You may not get this error but the error you do receive should point you in the right direction.

[Source](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4661)

Comment: Thank for your reply. I have spent half day yesterday trying this but end up 6 hours without solution. Logged in with run level 3, perform hald etc..got the error, and have created directory manuallly as a root but i get another error

Comment: For now I think I just fix it. i was getting an error that haldaemon was not able to access a file /var/cache/hald , I changed the ownership of the file and I can use and successfully use my mouse and keyboard !!! What a stress !!

Comment: Oh yeah, chown would fix that for you. Glad you got it working!